# How to use integrationFlows for new files?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I was following a tutorial on how to listen to a folder with spring integration and SseEmitter. I have this code now:

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow inboundFlow ( @Value("${input-dir:file:C:\\Users\\kader\\Desktop\\Scaned\\}") File in){
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Files.inboundAdapter(in).autoCreateDirectory(true),
            poller -> poller.poller(spec -> spec.fixedRate(1000L)))
            .transform(File.class, File::getAbsolutePath)
            .handle(String.class, (path, map) -> {
                sses.forEach((sse) -> {
                    try {
                        String p = path;
                        sse.send(SseEmitter.event().name("spring").data(p));
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                });
                return null ;
            })
            .get();
}
```

and it works but it sends all the files in the specified directory including the files that already exist, is there any way to make it ignore them and send the new files only???

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually since you don't configure any filters on the `Files.inboundAdapter()`, there is a logic like this:

```
    // no filters are provided
    else if (Boolean.FALSE.equals(this.preventDuplicates)) {
        filtersNeeded.add(new AcceptAllFileListFilter<File>());
    }
    else { // preventDuplicates is either TRUE or NULL
        filtersNeeded.add(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
    }
```

Therefore an `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` is applied and no any already polled files are not going to be picked up on the subsequent poll tasks.

However you really may talk about something like "after application restart", so yes, in this case all the files are going to be pulled.

I believe you need to study what is the `FileListFilter` and use an appropriate for your use-case: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/files.html#file-reading

Comment: Thanks, So are you saying that Files.inboundAdapter() doesn't listen for event and it just pull files and it accepts filters to be costumised

Comment: Correct. It does that periodically. Well, you can consider to use `useWatchService(true)` if you are really biased for events...

Comment: you mean WatchService instead of spring integration? I was considering that, does it go along with spring server sent events?

Comment: ??? I don't understand your concern. The `useWatchService(true)` is a part of the `Files.inboundAdapter()`. You shoudn't use anything instead.

Comment: I did but my reputation doesn't allow my vote to change the order, but it's recorded anyway

Comment: can you please provide me with some exemples on the use of useWatchService(true)  I tried it but nothing changed

Comment: What is your problem so? Can you just explain how to reproduce?

Comment: My problem is that " I only need to be notified on CREATE event, that's my use case"  and I  used 
     watchEvents(FileReadingMessageSource.WatchEventType.CREATE)     but nothing seem to have changed

Comment: in other words: how can i make it ignore the initial list of files in the directory?

Comment: Well, I believe you can do that with the `LastModifiedFileListFilter`

Comment: How can set the age in it to filter the files that have been there before the application start

Comment: Well, that’s already your business decision: the Framework can’t do that for you

Comment: I'm aware of that I'm just wondering if you can provide me with some documentation so I can make use it with my use case, and thanks

Comment: I read it.  The  LastModifiedFileListFilter   filters the files that are too young for the age provided but doesn't deal with the files that are too old which doesn't seem to help in my case

Comment: Yeah, there is also other filters for your choice,

Comment: See `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`

Comment: I believe it can help me, i understand it stores in a metadata but what's the prefix parametre for

Comment: Just to distinguish one filter from another when the store is shared between them